# Can't abort script on error in Try block using Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I have a simple try block in Applescript that tries to eject a disk, and if it throws an error, it's supposed to abort ("return"). It's working...and it properly shows an error if a file from the server is open...but it doesn't abort! It completely ignores the "return" line and keeps right on trucking. I cannot figure this out.

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to eject disk "My Disk"
on error e
    display alert e
    return
end try

log "Code is still running if this is logged."
```

This just will not stop running, even if there's an error.

Update: Try this code...

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to eject disk "My Disk"
on error
    return
end try

log "Code is still running if this is logged."
```

It fails in the same way, but error still displays! The try block just isn't catching the error at all. The Finder is displaying it. This is completely circumventing AppleScript entirely. There's no way to catch this error in AppleScript.

My workaround is this:

```
    try
        do shell script "diskutil unmount " & quoted form of "/Volumes/My Disk"
    on error
        eject disk "My Disk"
        return
    end try
```

The first part is a shell script which throws an error if it fails. The error is generic and not very helpful, so after catching the error, I ask the Finder to do the same, which then throws the "uncatchable" but still useful error. The script then ends as designed, and the error I want will display.

Comment: What I'm guessing is that a try block does not catch an error of this type.

Comment: Correct.  The error from the underlying routine is returned to the Finder, which handles it.  You would need to do something like `do shell script "diskutil eject /Volumes/whatever"` to catch the error yourself.

Comment: I ran the script (with `osascript test.osa`), got the alert and script returned properly.

Comment: I'm running it both in script editor and also as an application. MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: @red_menace when I do that, it returns a generic error, which isn't helpful. The Finder error will tell the user exactly what application is using it. I need to catch that error, but nothing I do works!

Comment: @user3439894 Try to eject a disk that is being used by the system. Your test does not prove anything.

Comment: I missed the part in your OP about an open file, sorry.

Comment: You should post your workaround as an answer not as part of the question. This way it may receive upvotes independent of the question itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Finder will always display the alert if you are using it to eject the disk - that is the reason for using the shell script.  The shell script does return an error, what kind of information are you wanting to get?

Comment: The shell script returns an error, but it's generic and doesn't explain why the unmounting failed. It just says it failed.

Comment: The appropriate process would be to first check if there are any open files on the disk and act accordingly before attempting to unmount/eject the target disk.

Comment: It is supposed to sometimes print stuff before returning the error, so you might try redirecting stderr, e.g. `do shell script "diskutil unmount " & (quoted form of "/Volumes/My Disk") & " 2>&1"`